# b-link of bootstrap-vue doesn't show textContent or innerHTML

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I am unable to get `textContent` from blink and change it. If I try the same with a tag or div tag, then it works fine.

```
<b-link
 :ref="index"
 v-b-toggle="`${index}`"
 @click="changeText(index)"
>View More</b-link>

changeText(index) {
 console.log(this.$refs[index][0].textContent); // undefined
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out from the vue js test cases how to do this
Normally this works

```
console.log(this.$refs[index][0].textContent);
```

but as bootstrap-vue will return vue component to access its element we need to use **$el** to access its properties.

```
console.log(this.$refs[index][0].$el.textContent);
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference between a `<div />` and `<b-link />` is, that the former is an actual native HTML tag while the latter is a component which provides some degree of abstraction. To learn more about that, I recommend reading about native [web components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components) and their [Vue counterparts](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Relation-to-Custom-Elements).

To change the content of your `<b-link />` you have to make use of [Vue's reactivity](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods):

```
let buttonText = 'View More';

<b-link
 :ref="index"
 v-b-toggle="`${index}`"
 @click="changeText(index)"
>{{ buttonText }}</b-link>

changeText(index) {
 console.log(viewMore); // undefined
 viewMore = 'View Less';
}
```